# OpenShift Spanning Cluster: Distribute Replicas evenly between datacenters

Tags: kubernetes, scheduler

I have an OpenShift Cluster which is spanned between two physical separated datacenters for georedundancy. The nodes are labeled according to their location.

Now i'm searching for a way to configure the scheduler in such a way that if a pod is running with one replica (which is in one of the two datacenters), and an additional replica is started, the additional replica starts in the other datacenters? So that if the deployment is running with an even number of replicas, the replicas are evenly distributed between both datacenters?

I was searching in the pod/node affinity documentation as well as scheduler configuration, but i didn't find anything i need. Maybe i'm just googling wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/admin_guide/scheduling/scheduler.html#configurable-priority-functions It would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you have given a label to the nodes, for instance **location**, check the labels with the following command

```
oc get nodes --show-labels
```

> ServiceAntiAffinity takes a label and ensures a good spread of the pods belonging to the same service across the group of nodes based on the label values

[Spread across datacenter](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/admin_guide/scheduling/scheduler.html#configurable-priority-functions)

you can add the following content inside the `/etc/origin/master/scheduler.json` file

```
 {
            "argument": {
                "serviceAntiAffinity": {
                    "label": "location"
                }
            },
            "name": "Location",
            "weight": 2
        }
```

Comment: I have searched kubernetes documentation and stumbled upon [failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/labels-annotations-taints/#failure-domainbetakubernetesiozone), which, in addition to SelectorSpreadPolicy in the scheduler seems to resolve my issue as well. Can you tell me the difference between both approaches?

Comment: My cluster is on bare metal, thus i do not have any personal experience